# MySQL Invalid field count in CSV import

Tags: mysql, csv, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to import a csv file in phpmyadmin. I'm getting the invlaid column count at the below line. As you can see the problem must be with single or double quotes. But I'm not able to resolve it?

```
1411571853,PHA form,Height,6' 2'"',22,NULL
```

I have the setting in csv import as:

Columns Seperated with: ,

Columns enclosed with: "

Columns escaped with: \

Lines terminated with: auto

Can anyone help me to resolve this?

Comment: I am not able to understand this 6' 2'"'. I think 6' 2''. ans is replace every single quote with two quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the quotes around the 2 to " and escape the " already there

6' 2'"'

to

6' 2"\""2

Comment: I think it is getting confused with " because columns can be enclosed with ".                                                                                                                   I think if you just escape the " i.e. 6' 2'\"', put a slash next to the " it should work. You could also change the Columns enclosed with character to a different character that is not in your dataset.